# lookup time in heap based priority queue for dijkstra algorithm

Tags: c++

I want to use priority_queue as vertex container for a dikjstra algorithm, after calling `extractMin` to get a vertex `u`, I find all adjacent vertex `v`, and then I might call `decreaseKey` for `v`, I known that the `decreaseKey` spend O(lgN) time, however, before calling `decreaseKey`, I have to first find the position of `v`.

I used `std::vector` and `std::make_heap/std::push_heap/std::pop_heap` to maintain the priority_queue, using this data structure, to find a specific data would spend O(N) time, which would make the O(lgN)  `decreaseKey` meaningless.

So, what is the common method for the vertex container in dikjstra algorithm, or should I add a member in `class Vertex` to keep its position in the heap?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you do not need to use `std::***_heap` functions; There already is [`priority_queue`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue) in STL.

As for updating values already in the heap, you may insert `pair`s of index and distance. And maintain a distance vector to verify if the distance is still valid or has got updated; something like:

```
typedef struct {
    size_t index;   /* index of vertex and the distance at which */
    int dist;       /* the vertex was pushed to the heap         */
} value_t;

/* `a` has less priority than `b` if it is further away */
const auto comp = [](const value_t & a, const value_t & b){
    return b.dist < a.dist;
};

priority_queue<value_t, vector<value_t>, decltype(comp)> heap(comp);

/* the *most current* shortest distances for all nodes */
vector<int> dist(n, inf);
```

Then the Dikjstra loop would be something like:

```
while(!heap.empty()) {
    const auto top = heap.top();
    heap.pop();

    if(dist[top.index] < top.dist) {
          /* the node has already been added at a  */
          /* shorter distance therefore skip it    */
          continue;
    }
    /* process the node & its neighbors */
    /* push to the heap neighbors which get their `dist` deccreased */
}
```

It is true that there may be multiple copies of a same node in the heap (at different distances where only one of them is still valid); but you may show that the size of the heap is `O(num. of edges)`, therfore the heap would still perform `O(log num. of nodes)`.

Comment: actually this is the method tha I am using, however, the fact that one node might be pushed many times makes me kind of annoying....